# Introducing elements in a variable of type ArrayList

Tags: java, list, class, oop, arraylist

I have to list patient names (using ArrayList) through a method (inside the class Hospital).I tried to write the code but I got stuck.  First I think I should add the names in ArrayList and then I think I should show them.But how can I do it?

```
class Hospital
{ Patient p;


 class Patient
 {

 private String name,adress;  
 private int age,phoneNumber,securityNumber;
 private char sex;

 Patient(String name,char sex,String adress,int age,int 
 phoneNumber,int securityNumber)
 {
 this.name=name;
 this.adress=adress;
 this.age=age;
 this.sex=sex;
 this.phoneNumber=phoneNumber;
 this.securityNumber=securityNumber;
 }

 String getName()
 {
     return name;
 }
 void setName(String nam)
 {
 name=nam;
 }

 void ShowListOfNames(List <Patient> pat)
 {
 for(Patient h:pat)
  System.out.println(h.getName());
  }
 }


 }



 public class Tarea23_1ago
 {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
Scanner x=new Scanner(System.in);
List  <Patient> pat=new ArrayList <Patient>();
pat.add(new Patient("dan",'f',"nuyoo",12,2356445,001));
pat.add(new Patient("fredy",'m',"idk",34,34657,002));
pat.add(new Patient("dan",'m',"west",21,345546,003));



}
```

Comment: You have never used your declared scanner

Comment: no, but that's not the problem, the problem is the code that I have to write to introduce the patient's names using ArrayList.  @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ

Comment: What do you want `ShowListOfNames` to do?  "Show" (print) a list of names?  Create a list of names?  Return a list of names to the caller?  It's not at all clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @ajb to return or to show (whatever) the names that I already have in the main class,

Comment: Java doesn't understand "whatever".  You have to decide.  That's your first job.

Comment: ok, to return then @ajb

Comment: What do you meant by * I got stuck*?

Comment: what's `NameList`? it's not declared anywhere... Did you try to compile your code ?

Comment: @alfasin It was supposed to be the method, the method that returns the list of the names. yes, it doesn't work

Comment: it looks like you got things messed up a bit: a hospital shouldn't have: age, phoneNumber, securityNumber or sex...

Comment: Start with a baby-steps (a smaller example), don't try to run when you don't know how to walk.

Comment: @Blasanka I mean that I have no idea on how to write the correct code to return the patient's names using ArrayList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// First of all, these data are of a patient, not of a hospital, so I renamed the class...
public class Patient
{
    private String name,address;
    private int age, phoneNumber, securityNumber;
    private char sex;

    // No need a no-argument-constructor
    public Patient(String name, char sex, String address, int age, int
            phoneNumber, int securityNumber)
    {
        // Just to remember: Java generates a super() call even if you do not write it out
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.age = age;
        this.sex = sex;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.securityNumber = securityNumber;
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name=name; }
}

// Now comes the part that is about more patients. Could be named a hospital...
public class Hospital
{
    // A list of patents
    private final List<Patient> patients =  new ArrayList<>();

    // Prints out the names of the patents on the list
    public void showListOfNames()
    {
        for(final Patient : this.patients)
        {
            System.out.println(patient.getName());
        }
    }

    // The main method. It does not have to be in a separated class...
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in); // Still not in use...
        final Hospital h = new Hospital(); // our hospital instance, with the list of patients

        // Adding patents to the hospital's list
        h.patients.add(new Patient("dan",'f',"nuyoo",12,2356445,001));
        h.patient.add(new Patient("fredy",'m',"idk",34,34657,002));
        h.patient.add(new Patient("dan",'m',"west",21,345546,003));

        // Printing out the names
        showListOfNames();
    }

}
```

Comment: yes I fixed the confusion about the patient and the hospital too

Comment: why did you use  `final`? here: `for(final Patient : this.patients)`

Comment: Yes. `final` means the variable cannot reassigned in the scope it lives. In the enhanced-for statement the variable scope is inside the loop's block, and there is no assignment for it, so it can be `final`...

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution- Use this

```
 void ShowListOfNames(List <Hospital> patient)
 {
    for(Hospital h:patient)
      System.out.println(h.getName());
    }
}
```